# xpatchcmd patch to makeindex

Tags: makeindex, xpatch

I want to use `zhmakeindex` to generate indexes in the language of Chinese, with an investigation of the package `imakeidx`, I try to patch the `\imki@exec` as

```
\xpatchcmd{\imki@exec}{\imki@program}{zhmakeindex}{}{}
```

this should be work since the default value of `\imki@program` is `makeindex`.

However, after I run `xelatex test.tex`, the log shows that the `makeindex` program are executed:

> runsystem(makeindex -s zh.ist test.idx)

So, why my patch not work as expected? and did there any solution to patch `zhmakeindex`?

### THE MME

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage[linkcolor=cyan,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\imki@exec}{\imki@program}{zhmakeindex}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeindex[intoc,columns=3,columnseprule=true,columnsep=5pt,options={-s zh.ist}]
\newcommand{\iemph}[1]{\uwave{#1}\index{#1|hyperpage}}

\title{中文索引处理}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
测试\iemph{三点形}\\
测试\iemph{二次曲线}\\
\newpage
\iemph{向量}\\
\iemph{共线}\\
\iemph{简比}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

THE `zh.ist`

```
preamble "\\begin{theindex}
  \\def\\seename{见}
  \\def\\alsoname{又见}
  \\providecommand*\\indexgroup[1]{%
    \\indexspace
    \\item \\textbf{#1}\\nopagebreak}\n"

postamble "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"

group_skip "\n\n  \\indexspace\n\n"

headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  %\n \\indexgroup{"
heading_suffix "} \n  %\n"

numhead_positive "数字"
numhead_negative "数字"
symhead_positive "符号"
symhead_negative "符号"

delim_0         " \\dotfill\\ "
delim_1         " \\dotfill\\ "
delim_2         " \\dotfill\\ "
```

Comment: Try `\def\imki@progdefault{zhmakeindex}` (untested, I don't have the programm and your fonts).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, it works! I only need to compile it with the `-shell-escape` option. Maybe you'd like to change it to an answer with some explanation?